# How to make a Javascript button onclick() call a function that opens a bootstrap modal with an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a bootstrap 4 modal that opens when a button is pressed inside a dynamically created element which makes an Ajax request to a form pre-populated with the data from the associated id, and then a button to save the updated information into the database.

Currently, the edit button opens a new page "editData" with the prepopulated data associated with the passed id, which then can be used to update the information upon pressing a button, and then returns to the previous page.

What are the methods that I can use to make the button open a modal on the current page that can provide the same function?

```js
function populateData(dataInput) {
  var row = $('<tr id=' + dataInput.id + '/>');
  $('#table').append(row);
  row.append($('<td>' + dataInput.name + '</td>'));
  row.append($('<td>' + dataInput.description + '</td>'));
  row.append($(
    '<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="edit" onclick="edit(' +
    dataInput.id + ')"/>'));
}

function edit(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/getData?id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
      var dataInput = JSON.parse(data)[0];
      window.location = '/editData?id=' + dataInput.id;

    }
  })
}
```

Here is the getData that dynamically populates the table

```js
app.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
  var content = {};
  mysql.pool.query('SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE id=?', [req.query.id],
    function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
      }
      content.results = JSON.stringify(rows);
      res.send(content.results);
    });
});
```

And here is the editData.handler content

```html
<div>
  <form id="form">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="">

    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  </form>
  <div class="centerButton">
    <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="save()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the modal markup?

Comment: I do not have one yet, as I wasn't sure how to implement this.

Comment: did you look into the bootstrap 4 documentation?

Comment: Yes. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/

Comment: you may want to look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: I have. Yes, I can make the modal popup when a button is pressed.
But I want the modal to contain the information from the ajax request shown on the edit function above.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312658/javascript-implementing-bootstrap-modal-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now JavaScript part to make ajax request and embed data into modal.

```
function populateData(dataInput) {
  var row = $('<tr id=' + dataInput.id + '/>');
  $('#table').append(row);
  row.append($('<td>' + dataInput.name + '</td>'));
  row.append($('<td>' + dataInput.description + '</td>'));

  //check that I have added attributes data-toggle and data-target to point example modal
  row.append($(
    '<td><input type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-warning" value="edit" onclick="edit(' +
    dataInput.id + ')"/>'));
}

function edit(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/getData?id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
      var dataInput = JSON.parse(data)[0];

      //commented following line and adding code to embed data into modal  
      //window.location = '/editData?id=' + dataInput.id;
      $('.modal-body').html('html that you want to show');
    }
  })
}
```

It works and here is a [demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/moghya/pen/JLXeMo).

Please make sure that you have include bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: The modal shows, but the Ajax call is not made, which causes the form that pops up to be empty

Comment: @T.C.please check demo on Codepen, I have used a placeholder api for demo purpose there.

Comment: I see in the example codepen that the the body of the modal is populated with some data, but how do you make the form that was originally in the "editData" page (which I have included into the modal body, prepopulate with the data associated with the id that was passed?

For example, in the codepen, "dataInput.title" is shown, but I need the form that is already in the body of the modal to populate with the data from the database associated with the id.

Comment: @T.C. if you can see I have populated the title into body the same way you keep your form already in the model and then add values to the input fields that you retrive from api.

Comment: that ignores the form itself, and just shows whatever that was passed, which in this case is the "dataInput.title"

Comment: @T.C. please see demo now, I have update it as per your requirements.

Comment: I see it work with the example url provided, but it does not work with mysql database.

Comment: I added the "getData" that dynamically gets the information from the database. with the given id.